# re2 regex expression that starts with From: and ends with domain.com

Tags: regex, re2

I'm trying to come up with a regex expression I can use for filtering incoming email to my Google Apps domain. I'm using Content Compliance to check if it's signed using DKIM and then see if the "From:" part of the header contains our domain name. If it's unsigned and DOES contain our domain name I'm sending it to quarantine.

The expression I have in place is probably over-complex and still missing things. Today it missed:

```
From: "Employee Name" <employeename@mydomain.com>
```

What I need is an re2 (the version Google uses) regex expression that will match:

```
From: any-combination-of-letters-and-special-characters@mydomain.com
```

I've been using the following but, it's missing some:

```
((From:)\s{0,1}([\w.+\-]{0,40})\s{0,1}(\W|^)[\w.+\-]{0,25}@(mydomain)\.com(\W))
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try [`From:\s{0,10}"[\w.+\s\-]{0,25}"\s{0,1}\W[\w.+\-]{0,25}@mydomain\.com\W`](https://regex101.com/r/sG7kE1/1).

Comment: Unfortunately they don't always follow the same format. Sometimes it will be like the one above but, other times it will be just `employeename@mydomain.com`

I really need something that matches when the string starts with `From:` and ends with `mydomain.com` no matter what comes in between.

Comment: The problem might be with the length. If this is the case where you cannot use `*` or `+` quantifers, `From:.*?@mydomain\.com` will not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For us, this is working. Thank you to everyone that helped!

```
^(From:).*@(mevion)\.com(\W)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
'(From)(:)(\\s+)(".*?")(\\s+)(\\<)((?:[a-z][a-z]+))(@)((?:[a-z][a-z\\.\\d\\-]+)\\.(?:[a-z][a-z\\-]+))(?![\\w\\.])(\\>)'
```

Here `From:` will be fixed.

```
"Employee Name" #can replace any string within quotes
<employeename@mydomain.com> #can replace any email within <> tag
```

For `@mydomain.com`

You may use this,

```
'(From)(:)(\\s+)(".*?")(\\s+)(\\<)[\\w\\.-]+(@)(mydomain\\.com)(\\>)'
```

Let me know if it helps

Comment: @Shc Final Judgement Also let me know if you need minor tweaks, I will update my answer according to your requirements, Thanks

Comment: Thank you Md. Mohsin. I need it to just match our domain. I'm using this to block people spoofing our domain when sending to us. Can the end part just be `mydomain\.com`?

Comment: Something that combines `^(From:)` and `@(mydomain)\.com$`

Comment: Does this look like it would work?
`^(From:).*@(mydomain)\.com(\W)$`

Comment: @Shc Final Judgement Updated the answer. Let me know if that helps

Comment: Thanks again Md Mohsin! I'm not sure but, I think the version of regex being used by Google is a little different. Your code seems to have more slashes than what I have to use. In the end this `^(From:).*@(mevion)\.com(\W)` seems to be catching everything but, I still appreciate your contribution!